# delete image from folder when new image is uploaded for php yiiframework

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am quite new to php yiiframework. I have users model where it takes users basic information including profile image but i have to delete a image file when I updates new image for my profile.
I uploaded file by using following method.

```
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);    
        $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);          
        if(isset($_POST['Users']))
        {                           
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];             
            $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image_path');
            $fileName = $milliseconds. '-' .$random;
            $model->image_path = $fileName;

            if($model->save())              
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/uploaded/'.$fileName);
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }    
        $data = PanXCore::getDataForCreateUser();
        $userRoles = new UserRoles();
        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
                'roles' => $data['roles'],
                'userRoles' => $userRoles               
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `unlink()` for example

```
unlink(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/uploaded/'. $oldfile);
```